# How to debug problem with identity provider in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I'm trying to set up Keycloak to us CAS as an OIDC identity provider. I've had this working in the past but can't get it to work now. Keycloak is configured using the "/cas/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration" endpoint and set the client ID and secret.
All standard stuff.

Keycloak redirects to CAS as expected, the user authenticates successfully against CAS and then is redirected back to Keycloak, but Keycloak then throws this error in the logs:

```
2020-12-07T14:34:03.706265042Z 14:34:03,616 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-1) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: No access_token from server.
2020-12-07T14:34:03.706301844Z  at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.verifyAccessToken(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:499)
2020-12-07T14:34:03.706308262Z  at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.getFederatedIdentity(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:360)
2020-12-07T14:34:03.706313243Z  at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:472)
```

This is with logging at DEBUG level. Not clear what is really wrong.

The logs on the CAS side look OK.

Any ideas what might be wrong here and how to debug this?

This is with Keycloak 10.0.2

Comment: From CAS, do you see an access_token generated?, I wonder also if your client_secret is correct..

Comment: From CAS all seems good, but Keycloak doesn't seem to like what CAS passes back.
The client_secret is correct.
How to debug what CAS returns and what Keycloak is unhappy about?